# Shell Script with time windows and a break in between

Tags: bash, shell, time, shellcode

I can't figure out how I could get that script to work the correct way.

The subscript will run if it is in the timeframe as example 0800 - 1700 and if it is NOT in the pause time 1200 - 1400.

Here is my shellscript.

```
if [[ "$socket8_timestart" -le "$timenow"  &&  "$timenow" -le "$socket8_timestop" ]] &&
[[ "$timenow" -lt "$socket8_breakstart"  &&  "$socket8_breakstop" -gt "$timenow" ]] ; then
subscript
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: I think your final clause should be reversed.  You want $timenow to be greater than $socket8_breakstop to resume the sub-script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"$timenow" -lt "$socket8_breakstart"  &&  "$socket8_breakstop" -gt "$timenow"
```

this condition give true only before break, not within break (as intended) but also not after break. which is probably the problem you see.

consider chaniging the logic slightly:

```
#!/bin/bash
timenow="1330"
socket8_timestart="900"
socket8_breakstart="1300"
socket8_breakstop="1400"
socket8_timestop="1500"

(( timenow > socket8_timestart &&
   timenow < socket8_timestop
)) && ((
   timenow < socket8_breakstart ||
   timenow > socket8_breakstop
)) && echo "running"
```

alternatively, don't look at break as exception, but split the whole interval into two, one pre-break and one post-break. run script if pre-break OR post-break matches.

Beware of leading zeroes in your times.
Pause testing has been put into a seperate clause for easier factoring. There's no need for an extra clause, but may simplify things.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but I cannot figure out how to solve the problem.

Comment: second part of your condition should express something like "if it's before break OR after break" instead of  "if it's before begin of break AND before end of break" - which is the case now.  There exists an OR operator, looking like  "||".   Consider to make your script more readable with contruct like   "if (( time < break )); then ...

Comment: if [[ "$socket8_timestart" -le "$timenow" && "$timenow" -le "$socket8_timestop" ]] && [[ "$timenow" -lt "$socket8_breakstart" || "$timenow" -gt "$socket8_breakstop" ]] ; then

Comment: As you're working with full hours `date +"%H" | awk '/^0/ {sub("0","");} {print}'`

Comment: Thanx, you folks are geniuses. Thanx for helping me out.

Comment: for factoring, consider a function "within" which you could call like  "within timenow breakstart breakend"  and returns true or false accordingly. those cascaded conditional clauses aren't always nice to read.    "within now start end && ! within now breakstart breakend" may show more clearly what your code intends to achieve